# What type of motor is in my 110 V, 9 A, variable-speed drill press? It is 60 years old

Tags: power-supply, motor, identification, motor-controller, controller

It quit working. It has AC power going to a small circuit board (which has a small transformer on it), but no power coming out to the motor. It has 2 brushes and a commutator.

I was thinking the problem is the control board, so I want to put an external speed controller on it, if the motor is okay, but which one? And which controller, 110 AC to DC or an AC to AC? The motor has no info on it at all. Probably either a DC or Universal, but I can't tell. Also, if it is a DC motor, how much voltage is max?  It has been in the family since new so I want try and to keep it.

Comment: Welcome! Be aware that questions about repair and use of equipment are generally off-topic here. Provide as much information as you can, especially photos, schematics, etc.

Comment: Did you inspect each brush? They just may be worn out or stuck. Type of controller depends in part on behaviour you want: For [universal motors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_motor), there used to be ones giving less reduction in RPM with increasing load than the unregulated motor at a voltage with the same no load speed.

Comment: That `small transformer` might be a choke. Any smallish capacitor near the brush holders or circuit board?

Comment: A variable speed motor of this vintage almost certainly uses a TRIAC or SCR to control speed by phase angle modulation, which essentially modifies pulse width. If the drill press plugs into a wall outlet and there are no other large components like a transformer or bridge rectifier, it is likely that this solid state component has failed. Find an inexpensive variable speed control made for an AC motor (such as a fan) and replace it. Please provide pictures and other info if you want more help or assurances that you won't blow it up.

Answer (score 1):

I wish you had posted pictures. Still, from your description, it's a universal motor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_motor): it works both with AC and DC.

To troubleshoot, start with a meter in the Ohm range and see where there is a loss of continuity.

Comment: While it's likely, I don't see that this can be concluded from the meager information provided.

Comment: (FWIW, the question is tagged [tag:universal-motor].)

Comment: Is this tag proven to be correct? If so, the main question is somehow hollow...

Comment: The question also says that the motor has two brushes.  Two brushes + AC = universal motor.

Comment: @JRE Two brushes + AC + rectifier = DC motor. Treadmills commonly use(d?) this for example. The constant RPM of a PMDC would be attractive for a drill press, but that's hardly conclusive either (consider a Dremel tool with drill press attachment).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a small circuit board, there can be a rectifier, thus the motor can be DC. Anyway, my suggestion is to remove the motor from the board and connect an incandescent light bulb (those old, resistive ones) to the board as if it were the motor. Then use a multimeter to check the voltage in the lamp. If no voltage at all, the problem is probably the board (based on the info we got). If there is voltage, you can check if it is DC or AC, and also the voltage levels. Then you can shop for a speed controller that provides an equivalent voltage.

Edit: For the light bulb, I suggest to use those 220V ones (or whatever the mains voltage in your region is). If you put those automotive 12V ones, they will burn if the voltage the board supplies is larger than that, which can very well be, given the info we got.

Comment: There is AC power going to the circuit board but none coming out, AC or DC.

Comment: the circuit board has 110AC going to it but no power out(AC or DC). the motor will spin with a car battery and is 1.5 OHMs  between the input wires.  Main question for me is do I have a universal motor and buy a controller for AC to AC or a controller AC to DC.   Do I apply AC voltage to it and see if it runs then buy AC to AC controller? which would be better since this did go up to 3000 rpm.

Comment: If it ran with a 12V car battery, you should not connect it to 110V, it would very likely burn the motor. I suggest getting an AC to DC controller, given that it is confirmed to run with 12V DC. The question now is the output voltage and current the controller should supply. With the info I've got, the best I can suggest is to connector the motor to its mechanical load and gradually increase the voltage until it drives the load with proper speed.

Comment: As for the current rating, you can look for the closest fuse or breaker on the AC side of the controller and get a controller with the same current rating. I suggest also, of course, to check the mechanical load. You could try to make sure that, for example, it is not blocked and also that it is well oiled.

Comment: @Joe "Main question for me is do I have a universal motor ". As I already said: post pictures. We're all wasting time playing a guessing game because you're not posting pictures.

Comment: I have tried to post pictures but they won't upload (over the  2mb limit from my iphone).  Thanks Vic , that was very helpful...I will try to run it on a DC controller.....the outside name  plate of drill says 120v, 9amp,60hz.....the GE brand switch inside has a reset button and says 17A 120V and below that 1-1/8HP 120V AC but this is prior to the circuit board.